# Date from UserForm not formated properly in Column search

Tags: vba, excel, date, search

I am quite new at VBA and with no programming background so it might be simple question.

I work with simple Excel data table and created UserForm to ease up entering new information. One of the fields is date. Then I enter date into UserForm TextBox, it converts it to needed format (yyyy-mm-dd) and fills cell.

Problem is that despite the fact that the date and its format looks the same, but in the Table column search it appears like different kind of entry and not included into automatic groups and subgroups. I want it to be grouped to year, month, groups like the dates entered by hand.

[image: Visualization of problem]

Code used to adjust entered date format:

```
Private Sub TB_Gavimo_data_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

If TB_Gavimo_data.Text <> "" Then
    If IsDate(TB_Gavimo_data.Text) Then
        TB_Gavimo_data.Text = Format(TB_Gavimo_data.Text, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Else
        MsgBox "Įveskite teisingą datos formatą"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If
```

Code used to populate cell from UserForm Text Box

```
Private Sub Save_Click()

  Worksheets("Registracija").Range("F3") = TB_Gavimo_data

  Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Cast to Date - `Worksheets("Registracija").Range("F3") = CDate(TB_Gavimo_data)`

Comment: Convert a text date into a value using `Worksheets("Registracija").Range("F3").Value = DateValue(TB_Gavimo_data)`. Otherwise you save the date as text but not as date format. `Format()` always returns a string not a date.